# Style content inside Google Custom Search iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-custom-search

I'm trying to style a specific div (#cse-hosted) which is the first div inside the body of the Google CSE iFrame.  I know you can use the following to set a width for the iFrame using JavaScript variables:

```
var googleSearchFrameWidth = 'xxx';
```

But is there anything like that which allows me to go inside the iFrame and style the divs?

I've been searching the web and have found no solutions so there exists the likelihood that there is no way to do what I'm hoping, but...

Anyways, I'm sorry to be so abrupt, but I'd prefer not to give away any other content if at all possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot style content that is not on your current page (without javacsript), and you cannot use javascript cross-domain.  Unless you have access to the code for the iframe, you aren't going to be able to do much.